# Adding time to day speficied dates in R

Tags: r

I want to add hours to day specified dates. And I want the output to be in date format. I wrote the below code:

```
day<-as.Date(c("20-01-2016", "21-01-2016", "22-01-2016", "23-01-2016"),format="%d-%m-%Y")
hour<-c("12:00:00")
date<-as.Date(paste(day,hour), format="%d-%m-%Y %h:%m:%s")
```

However, This code produces NA's:

```
> date
[1] NA NA NA NA
```

How can I do this in R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

The below code also doesn't work:

```
day<-as.Date(c("20-01-2016", "21-01-2016", "22-01-2016", "23-01-2016"),format="%d-%m-%Y")
time <- "12:00:00"
x <- paste(day, time)
x1<-as.POSIXct(x, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

It still prodeces NAs:

```
> x1
[1] NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: %H:%M:%S - they're capitals for the time format. Also try as.POSIXct instead of as.Date in the second cast as the date format doesn't include time information

Comment: It didn't work. Still getting NAs @Akhil Nair

Comment: Why only '12:00:00'? Do you perhaps have the rest of the hours showing as expected? (i.e. `21-01-2016 01:00:00, 21-01-2016 02:00:00`, etc...)

Comment: All hours are the same @Sotos.

Comment: Just try `as.POSIXct(paste(day,hour))`.

Comment: @oercim, your second attempt does not work because you have mixed your original code with my first answer attempt instead of just replacing your code with mine. Note the differences in my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either of these two:

```
dates <- as.Date(c("20-01-2016", "21-01-2016", "22-01-2016", "23-01-2016"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
time <- "12:00:00"
x <- paste(dates, time)
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

dates <- c("20-01-2016", "21-01-2016", "22-01-2016", "23-01-2016")
time <- "12:00:00"
x <- paste(dates, time)
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I personally find the second version simpler.

Comment: This didn't work for me @Samuel. I guess since my "dates" field is in date format.

Comment: You are right @nicola. Reversing Y and d make the code work. But I didn't understand why we reversed it. In date field day is first element of the date and year is the third element. Thanks a lot to all.

Comment: The day field was the first when you had the string. After coercing to a `Date` object, the fields are in the standard order (`Y-m-d`). See it with `print(day)`. I edited the answer to reflect this change.